# New menu in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

Is it possible to create a menu like below? (Sorry for the quality of the picture :P)

[image]

It is possible? If yes then how?

Comment: Have a look at this question and the answers given their:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377472/slide-out-menu-like-android-google-and-youtube-style-slide-menu-not-like-faceb

Comment: also look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678595/how-to-create-slide-layout-animation-in-android/ just need to give `position="left"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use sliding drawer just check it out :
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/01/slidingdrawer-in-android-a-simple-example/

Answer (score 0):

You could be interested in the [sliding menu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial for [Sliding Menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

There are plenty of tutorials and samples on the web for what you are looking for.