# Android semi transparent sliding drawer

Tags: android, drawer

I want to make an iOS 7 like drawer that I can slide from the bottom that doesn't cover the full screen and is semi transparent/blurred on Android.

I had a look at [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) on android to try and get a start but it looks like its being depreciated. How can I create a similar future proof effect on android?

Comment: This might help you out?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678595/how-to-create-slide-layout-animation-in-android

Answer (score 2):

Just change the background color of the List view that gets populated in navigation drawer fragment.

use of background color "#22FFFFFF" makes navigation drawer semitransparent

Use an hexadecimal color code, which consists of two digits for alpha and six for the color itself, like this:

use android:background ="#88676767" change the first 88 to your selection of opacity

android:background="#c0000000" -for more darkness

Please rate it if it turns helpful.

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:background="#22FFFFFF"
tools:context="com.Navigation Drawer Fragment" />
```